# ¿Cómo restar/sustraer, multiplicar y dividir elementos de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Verán quizá la pregunta es muy tonta pero recientemente me metí a un curso de Python (básico) y en mi proyecto final quiero hacer una calculadora.

La suma la solventé usando lista y con la función sum(lista)

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer una resta/sustracción?
Me explico, no quiero que sea una lista grande (no se si hay manera más eficiente que no sea en lista)

Algo como:

```
resta = []
a = int(input("Introduce el primero número:    "))
resta.append(a)
restamenu()
```

Suponiendo que a fuera 10, la "lista" quedaría resta = [10] ¿no?
Continuando:

```
def restamenu():
    resnum = str(input("¿Deseas agregar un número? [S/N]"))
    resnum = resnum.lower()
    if resnum == "s":
    b = int(input("Introduce el número:    "))
```

Aquí es donde tengo el problema, lo que quiero hacer es que al poner la variable `b` esta se reste con `resta`, o sea:

```
resta = [10]
b = 2
resta = [8]
```

Tomando en cuenta que `def restamenu()` volverá a ser invocada por lo que se pedirá una nueva variable `b` que volverá a ser restada con `resta`.

Mi idea es, dado que no se puede restar un `int` con una lista (que yo sepa), hacer `b` una lista también, de modo que quedaría:

```
resta = [10]
b = [[2]]
resta = [8]
```

El segundo problema es mi código:

```
opcion = int(input("Selecciona una operación:     "))
    elif opcion == 2:
        a = int(input("Introduce el primero número:    "))
        restatotal = []
        resta1 = []
        restatotal.append(a)
        print(restatotal)
        restar()

def restar():
    print()
    SoN = str(input("¿Deseas agregar un número? [S/N]"))
    SoN = SoN.lower()
    if SoN == "s":
        b = int(input("Introduce el número:    "))
        resta1.append(b)
        restatotal.append(list(np.array(restatotal) - np.array(resta1)))
        restatotal.pop(0)
        print(restatotal)
        restar()
    elif resnum == "n":
        print(restatotal)
    else:
        print("nel")
```

El primer número mas o menos bien, lo imprime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero después de añadir más:
2da vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3ra vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Ayuda por favor!
Gracias.

Comment: Y por que guardarlos en una lista? no creo que sea necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nota inicial**

El código que presentas es bastante farragoso y podría mejorarse. Por ejemplo, separando "responsabilidades" en las funciones, de modo que cada función que escribas tenga una responsabilidad única, y no mezclar diferentes cosas en la misma función. Así, por ejemplo, la parte que ofrece opciones al usuario y  lee una de ellas (menú), no debería realizar cómputos con listas, sino limitarse a mostrar el menú y retornar la opción elegida. Podrías también tener otra función que lea números repetidas veces para guardarlos en una lista hasta que el usuario decida no meter más. Y después funciones que hagan los cálculos adecuados sobre las listas. Finalmente una función "principal" iría llamando a las anteriores en el orden que corresponda. Por ejemplo, primero para pedir una lista, después al menú para pedir qué hacer con ella y finalmente a la función que realiza la operación.

**Restar o multiplicar elementos de una lista, usando `reduce()`**

Pero centrándonos ya en lo que preguntas, creo que lo que buscas es la función `reduce()`.

La función `reduce()` forma parte de un paradigma de programación llamado "*programación funcional*", en el que se intentan ocultar los bucles dejando que sean otras funciones como `map()` o `reduce()` las que hagan las iteraciones. En cada iteración es necesario realizar quizás alguna transformación de los datos (para lo que se usaría `map()`), o bie realizar algún tipo de "agregación" de modo que toda una lista se reduzca al final a un solo resultado numérico (para lo que se usaría `reduce()`).

Inicialmente `reduce()` formaba parte del lenguaje Python, pero a partir de la versión 3 se le ha relegado a un módulo de la biblioteca estándar, por no ser demasiado usada y disponer el lenguaje de otras alternativas más legibles (bucles explícitos). Si quieres usarla con python3 debes comenzar por:

```
from functools import reduce
```

La forma de usarla es así:

```
resultado = reduce(funcion, iterable)
```

Lo que hace `reduce()` es iterar por los elementos del iterable, de uno en uno, y realizar una llamada a la `funcion` que le hayas pasado como primer parámetro, pasándole como argumentos el resultado anterior, y el elemento actual del iterable. En la primera iteración, en lugar del resultado anterior se pasa el primer elemento del iterable.

Si por ejemplo la función que le pasas se limitara a sumar dos números:

```
def sumar(x,y):
  return x+y
```

y lo usas así:

```
lista = [ 20, 10, 5, 4 ]
resultado = reduce(sumar, lista)
```

El resultado saldrá 39, pues `reduce()` irá iterando y llamando a `sumar()` en la forma siguiente. En la primera iteración se le pasa a `sumar()` los números 20 y 10, lo que retorna 30; en la siguiente iteración se la pasa 30 (el resultado anterior) y 5 (el elemento siguiente), lo que retorna 35, y en la siguiente se le pasa 35 y 5, lo que retorna 39 que s por tanto el resultado final.

Naturalmente para sumar no necesitamos `reduce()`, pues tenemos `sum()` que hace exactamente lo mismo. Pero la gracia de `reduce()` es que cambiando la función que le pasas como parámetro te puede servir también para restar, o para multiplicar, o para encontrar el máximo, o cualquier cosa que se te ocurra. Mira:

```
def restar(x,y): 
  return x-y
def multiplicar(x,y): 
  return x*y
def mayor(x,y):
  if x>y:
    return x
  else:
    return y

>>> reduce(restar, lista)
1

>>> reduce(multiplicar, lista)
4000

>>> reduce(mayor, lista)
20
```

**Nota adicional**

Cuando las funciones que le quieras pasar a `reduce()` (o a cualquier otra función que admita una función como parámetro) son tan sencillas que constan simplemente de un `return (expresión)`, puedes escribir una `lambda` en su lugar. Una lambda es una función sin nombre que se escribe en el mismo lugar en el que la estás pasando como parámetro, y que sólo puede contener en su "cuerpo" una expresión que es lo que retornará como resultado al ser llamada. Entonces podríamos haber hecho:

```
suma = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, lista)
resta = reduce(lambda x,y: x-y, lista)
producto = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay formas mas sencillas de hacer lo que pides, en este caso hice un código talvez algo complejo para ti, pero tratare de explicarlo, primero vamos a usar la función `sum()` para sumar listas, para crear algunas listas usaremos *compresión de listas* y por ultimo para hacer algunos *"trucos"* usaremos expresiones lambda.

**Espresiones Lambda**
Son algo parecidas a las funciones anónimas de `JavaScript`, estas funciones sirven para hacer operaciones cortas y concretas por ejemplo elevar al cuadrado un numero.

```py
#nombre funcion  lambda  parametro : operacion
elevar_cuadrado = lambda x: x**2 

x = elevar_cuadrado(2)
#salida -> 4
```

No es muy difícil de entender, el nombre de la variable será nuestra función, luego se indica que será una función lambda con la palabra reservada `lambda`, posteriormente se le indica los *parametros* que recibirá finalmente los dos puntos (`:`) seguido de la operación a realizar.

**Compresión de listas**
La compresión de lista es una forma fácil, rápida y sencilla de hacer un ciclo `for` que nos retornara una lista, por ejemplo convertir números en formato de String a entero.

```py
numeros = ['1','2','4','10']

#    operacion a realizar - variable - iterable
numeros = [int(x) for x in numeros]

#equivalente a 
nums = []
for x in numeros:
    x = int(x)
    nums.append(x)
```

Esto tampoco es muy difícil, primero indicamos la operación a realizar, luego declaramos la variable que obtendremos del objeto iterable, finalmente se indica el objeto a iterar.

Una vez entendido eso podemos pasar al codigo.

Primero creamos una lista de opciones conformadas por tuplas

```py
#         opcion, operacion  
opciones = [('0','sumar'),('1','restar'),('2','multiplicar')]

#imprimimos la lista de opciones
for n,op in opciones:
    #n es el numero y op es la operación
    print(f"{n}.-{op}")

#pedimos que ingrese la opción que desee 
opcion = input('Ingrese la operacion que desea realizar: ')
```

Bien ahora que tenemos la opción faltaría validarla, es decir que exista en la lista de opciones, para eso usamos una expresión lambda,, para obtener el primer elemento de cada tupla.

```py
#obtenemos los primeros indices (0,1,2,...,n)
options = lambda opciones: [opcion[0] for opcion in opciones]
lista_opciones = options(opciones)
```

Mas adelante explicare otra forma sencilla se hacer la validación, ahora comprobaremos la opción ingresada.

```
#verificamos si se encuentra en la lista de opciones
if opcion in lista_opciones:
    #suma
    if opcion == "0":
       #le pedimos que ingrese los numeros de esta forma: 1+2+3
        numeros = input("ingrese los numeros a sumar (n+m..): ")
        numeros = numeros.split("+") #separamos los numero por el signo +
        numeros = [int(n) for n in numeros] #convertimos a entero para poder operar
        suma = sum(numeros)#utilizamos la funcion sum para sumar elementos de una lista
        print(f"la suma es {suma}")

    #la resta
    elif opcion == "1":
        #de igual forma pedimos los numero: 10-2-4
        numeros = input("ingrese los numeros a restar (n-m..): ")
        numeros = numeros.split("-") #separamos por el signo -

        resta = int(numeros[0])#obtenemos el primer elemento, ejemplo 10
        #hacemos un ciclo for para restar
        for n in numeros[1:]: #restamos desde el segundo elemento
          n = int(n)
          resta-=n
        print(resta)
```

Lo que hacemos en la parte de restar es pedir los números ejemplo `10-3-2`, luego separaremos los números por el signo `-`, lo que nos devuelve una lista `['10','3','2']`, luego convertimos a entero los números para poder operar, esto con la compresión de lista.  ahora necesitamos restar, lo cual hacemos con un ciclo `for`, pero... como indicamos cual será el primer numero al que se le restara?, facil escogemos al primer elemento de la lista de números `[10,3,2]`, que seria en este caso `10`, luego le decimos que coja los números restantes, es decir desde la posición 1 en adelante `numeros[1:]`, y listo eso seria todo.

La otra forma de validar si la opcion ingresada es correcta seria de la siguiente forma.

```py
opciones = [('0','sumar'),('1','restar'),('2','multiplicar')]

...

opcion = input('Ingrese la operacion que desea realizar: ')

opcion = int(opcion) # convertimos a enteror para poder operar
#validamos la opcion
if opcion in range(0,len(opciones)):
    ....
```

Aquí le decimos que verifique si la opción ingresada esta dentro del rango de 0 hasta el tamaño de la lista de opciones, si decides usar esta opción tendrás que cambiar los *ifs* posteriores a `if opccion == 0`, tendrás que hacer la comparación con enteros `0, 1,2 .. ect` y ya no con strings `'0','1','2',...'etc'`.
Espero haberte ayudado y que hayas aprendido a como usar algunas cosas nuevas :).

Comment: Ya veo, gracias. La razón por la que lo hice en listas es porque básicamente es lo que me han enseñado. Mis opciones de funciones son algo básicas por lo que me apaño con lo que tengo. Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta.